# How to save captured photos as jpg files on android camera2

Tags: android, kotlin, android-camera2

current when I click capture button,

show camera preview capture image on Imageview..

but I want to save camera preview capture image in jpg format. in my storage.

How to save my capture image? on `/sdcard/DCIM/' folder.

```
//click button.
captureBtn.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
    view -> takePicture()
}

fun takePicture() {
   mCameraDevice?.createCaptureSession(arrayListOf(mImageReader?.surface), mSessionCallback, null)
}

private val mSessionCallback = object : CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
   override fun onConfigured(cameraCaptureSession: CameraCaptureSession?) {
       if (mCameraDevice == null) {
           return
       }

       mCaptureSession = cameraCaptureSession
       val captureBuilder = mCameraDevice?.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE)
       captureBuilder?.addTarget(mImageReader!!.surface)
       mCaptureSession?.capture(captureBuilder?.build(), mCaptureCallback, null)
     }
   }


   private val mCaptureCallback = object : CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {

    override fun onCaptureProgressed(session: CameraCaptureSession?, request: CaptureRequest?, partialResult: CaptureResult?) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Partial result")
    }

    override fun onCaptureFailed(session: CameraCaptureSession?, request: CaptureRequest?, failure: CaptureFailure?) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Capture session failed")
    }

    override fun onCaptureCompleted(session: CameraCaptureSession?, request: CaptureRequest?, result: TotalCaptureResult?) {
        session?.close()
        mCaptureSession = null
        Log.d(TAG, "Capture session closed")
    }
}
```

this source show camera preview capture on ImageView.

I want capture photo, save jpg file.

how to save capture image?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer source of camera2 basic:
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic/tree/master/kotlinApp

Or
[Why Camera2 API working not correct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547673/why-camera2-api-working-not-correct)

Comment: I have the same question, I am completely new to Android ... I built the debug version of the camera2 sample and installed it (it runs).  Despite taking several pictures, I don't see any either on the device or SD card.  Do I need to do something special?  The code looks like it tries to write the data out.

Comment: You can create a folder in SD card and save file into : Ex: String folder = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/MyAppTest"  ;
File mediaStorageDir = new File(folder);
if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
 if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
  Log.d("MyCameraApp", "failed to create directory");
  return null;
 }
}
File mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +  "test.jpg");